# GNU Tool to find memory leak on windows

Tags: gcc, memory-leaks, mingw, gnu

I am trying to use the tools in the mingw toolkit, g++, gdb, gprof etc... but is there any way to detect memory leaks in gprof (the profiler) or gdb. I have heard that detecting leaks in gdb is possible in hp-unix, but for it isn't for windows. the reason I am trying to stick to gnu is because my computer has a 40GB hard that is already gunked programs pictures and videos. I have tried moving them to a seperate drive. and now that is running out of space... now both my hard disc and external drive are full. also the computer has an intel pentium 4 processer. so getting, for instance visual studio. is out of the question...
also it's sort of a moral thing... I hate when you search how to compile a library or something. and they just say: "compile it with visual c++", I hate that. so when I find all the tools I need in the gnu-toolkit. I feel like I can spit on visual c++ and go 'HAH'

I have heard of valgrind, but it's only for linux and mac. so in conclusion

ARE THERE ANY GNU TOOLS THAT CAN DETECT MEMORY LEAKS ON WINDOWS

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows ?

Comment: @Ernest, it's not so much a duplicate. I am more so lookng into a tool that comes in mingw-toolset (you know what I mean: g++ gcc gdb gprof)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [deleaker](https://www.deleaker.com/) - is a powerful tool to control leaks of resources.
Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this http://wyw.dcweb.cn/leakage.htm